# get all duplicate data on one date in one my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table  that have date and status column. multiple values of status insert on one date. I want that how many duplicate value are insert on one date.

For example:

```
            -------------------
            |date     | status|
            -------------------
            |2014-2-14|   1   |
            -------------------
            |2014-2-14|   1   |
            -------------------               
            |2014-2-15|   0   |
            -------------------
            |2014-2-13|   2   |
            -------------------
```

I want flowing output

```
            -------------------
            |date     | total status|
            -------------------
            |2014-2-14|   2   |
            -------------------
            |2014-2-14|   1   |
            -------------------               
            |2014-2-15|   1   |
```

Comment: The missing "2014-02-13" is intentional ?

Answer (score 1):

You're expected result is weird, because there is no `2014-2-13` at all, but I guess it's just a type.

Anyway, looks like you need `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(DISTINCT Status)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Date
```

It will give you number of distinct statuses added for each day. If you want to count all statuses and you don't care if they were distinct, just skip `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(Status)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Date
```